# Go back Javascript not working for Safari

Tags: javascript, safari

I am trying to implement a go back button using javascript. The code below works fine for ie and firefox. It doesnt work for safari though. Any ideas to fix the problem?

```
<A href="javascript:history.back()"><IMG border=0 src="imageurl1"></A>`

 I tried history.go(-1) as well.
```

Thanks,

Comment: Are you getting any errors? You can enable developer tools from Safari preferences

Comment: Can't reproduce this behavior in Safari for Windows. Maybe javascript is disabled in your safari?

Comment: no hjavascript is enabled. go back button is not working the same way as it is working for IE.

Comment: in some weired circumstances this javascript method doesn't work. You can find the same behaviour also in Mozilla's browser (I know it from the Mozilla Suite Browser 1.7.x and from FireFox 2). I've never seen that in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Any other ways to implement back button other than javascript?

Comment: It exists the method 'document.referrer'. This contains the uri of page which has called the current site. But this way has a big disadvantage. This one works only if the site has been requested by 'http://...'. Another thing is, some browser can block this property. However, there is no other way to implement the back button.

Comment: I used document.referrer but still no luck. <a href="javascript:history.go(-1)" onMouseOver="self.status=document.referrer;return true">BACK</a>

Comment: Am i missing anyhthing?

Comment: Replace in href history.back by document.referrer. But remember, there is no garantuee that it does work.

Answer (score 0):

You can try making a function with preventDefault like this:

```
function goBackHistory(){
  history.go(-1);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

and then call function from html

```
<a href="javascript:goBackHistory()"><IMG border=0 src="imageurl1"></a>
```